# Sample ''Hola'" Rubygem push error on windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am following the very basic tutorial found here: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

**hola_username.rb:**

```
class Hola
  def self.hi
    puts "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

**hola_username.gemspec:**

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'hola_username'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2010-04-28'
  s.summary     = "Hola!"
  s.description = "A simple hello world gem"
  s.authors     = ["Surname Lastname"]
  s.email       = 'me.me@gmail.com'
  s.files       = ["lib/hola_username.rb"]
  s.homepage    =
    'http://rubygems.org/gems/hola_username'
  s.license       = 'MIT'
end
```

That really is all there is to the project.

I can build my gem with

```
gem build .\hola_username.gemspec
```

I have also tested it by importing and executing the hi function of the Hola class and it works:

```
PS E:\hola_username> gem install .\hola_username-0.0.0.gem
Successfully installed hola_username-0.0.0
Parsing documentation for hola_username-0.0.0
Done installing documentation for hola_username after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

&

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'hola_username'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Hola.hi
Hello world!
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

But when I try to

```
gem push .\hola_username-0.0.0.gem
```

I get:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Psych::SyntaxError)
>       (): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1

Any ideas?

*Edit: I am on a windows 10 machine using ruby 2.0.0p598*

**Edit v01: *Anything* I put after gem push will result in the above error, doesn't seem to be a problem with the sample rubygem.**

**Edit v02: My credentials file that was generated in the .gem folder however stars with hex characters: fffe2d002d00.. Which might be the ones causing trouble?**

Comment: I think you're using the wrong backslash? `\ ` instead of `/`

Comment: @maxpleaner Note “I am on Windows 10.”

Comment: Sorry yeah i see that

Comment: The gemspec has a syntax error, you have not closed quotes on homepage line - is that the same in your project?

Comment: @neilslater No sorry that's just an error created with copying, will edit original post

Comment: @mudasobwa: I think Ruby could well handle that differently though, and very simple to do `gem push hola_username-0.0.0.gem` instead, which should work (the `./` for file in current path is not required) so worth a try.

Comment: @NeilSlater gem push hola_username-0.0.0.gem returns the exact same error

Comment: Following your edit, is it possible when you signed up at `https://rubygems.org/sign_up` that you used non-ASCII characters in your username or password that would be different depending on which character encoding was in play?

Comment: @NeilSlater I have not used any non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My credentials file in .gem folder was encoded with UCS2 - Little Endian and converting it to UTF without BOM did the trick.

Although I have absolutey no idea why..